# My iPhone 6s was stolen

Tags: iphone, icloud

My iPhone 6s was stolen 4 days ago. I know it was stolen because I saw it on a cctv footage. I already reported to the police. We haven't caught the theft yet and I am here trying to move on from it. I'm really looking forward to find answers to my concerns.

I use my "fingerprint" as an unlock code to my phone but if my phone can't read my finger it shows a 4 digit code. I opened my apple id using my laptop and i found out that my apple id is still signed in to my iphone but its offline and the theft haven't hacked or opened my phone yet. So what I did was change my apple id's name, bday, and password. Next is I opened my iCloud, its too late when i realized that I set the Find My iPhone on my phone. So, I opened find my iPhone but i can't locate it because it was offline. But I set the Alarm sound and Lock mode for my iPhone. I even changed all my accounts and social media passwords thinking that it might protect my accounts from being hacked or used by the theft.

I asked people here and they said that, "there's no place or people here that can hacked iPhone 6s" and "if you have iCloud signed in to your iPhone its impossible for the  theft to hacked your phone." I don't know if this is true or not, but I hope so too. I'm still hoping that I could retrieve my iPhone from the theft.

Is there anything more that I can do to protect my iPhone? 
Does the theft really haven't hacked my iPhone yet?
Will the theft be able to make use of my iPhone?
Will the theft be able to format my phone?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the phone is on your iCloud account with 'find my phone' enabled they shouldn't be able to re-activate it.

If you're really concerned about what's on your phone being found you can remotely wipe it https://support.apple.com/kb/ph2701?locale=en_US.

Comment: Really? I'm relieved. Thank you. Btw the theft was caught earlier. Unfortunately, we can't get useful info from her. She said that she already sold the phone but the investigator won't believe it. We decided to file a case to the theft.

Comment: Best to remotely wipe a lost iphone. You can always easily restore it form backups if you get it back. But wiping is the safest way to go. I would not bother changing all my passwords. There's just no need.

Comment: The phone's basically useless to anyone else if it has an iCloud lock on it. You should still cancel your sim card so nobody puts it in a different phone and makes calls.

Comment: @l008com  if i wipe it, is there still no chance for the theft to benefit my phone?